# Logistic Regression in R with GLM giving negative probabilities even with type already as "response"

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I'm trying to verify the assumptions of logistic regression in R. To do this I first computed the probabilities as in the following code for the [sample dataset here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cwsSoHEJ7q32rTVpLBcV4OCtD0E3tsHX/view?usp=sharing):

```
data <- read.csv('log_reg_example.csv', header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, na.strings=c("", "NA"))
data <- na.omit(data)

model <- glm(data$outcome ~ data$f1 + data$f2 + data$f3
    
probabilities <- predict(model, type = "response")

print("Probabilities")
print(probabilities)

predicted.classes <- ifelse(probabilities > 0.5, "pos", "neg")

logit <- log(probabilities/(1-probabilities))
print(logit)
```

However, some of these probabilities turned out to be negative negative which is causing problems when I try to compute the logit. How is it possible that there are negative probabilities? I've looked at many answers on here that just suggest to use "response" type but I already had that from the beginning.

Any ideas?

Comment: A reproducible example would make this easier to answer.

Comment: I edited my question to have a reproducible example in the answer in case it's useful for anyone. @Stephan Kolassa's answer below turned out to solve my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the `Usage` section of the help page to `?glm`:

> `glm(formula, family = gaussian, ...`

That is, the default value of the `family` parameter is `gaussian`. By default, `glm()` fits a "normal" regression with a conditional normal distribution. And of course, fits from such a model can be negative.

To run a logistic regression, replace your command with

```
model <- glm(data$outcome ~ data$f1 + data$f2 + data$f3, family=binomial)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the issue and I don't have the issue anymore.

Comment: You should never use `$` within R model formulas. Lot's of stuff can go awry if you do, in particular `predict` won't work. Use the `data` argument of the model function.